# How to make two product columns for a specific collection in shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to change the number of columns for a specific collection. Right now collection is set to four columns but i would like the one collection to be only two columns. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. clone the current collection liquid with 4 columns
2. edit the clone file to have only 2 columns
3. Assign this new 2 column collection some products
4. hook up this collection with 2 columns to navigation

In other words, assign your specific collection a different collection template, one with 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to adjust the css class for the grid on the collection page. Every theme is different so there is no clear cut answer. Typically you would need to open the collection.liquid section file and look for `grid_item one-quarter` or something similar and adjust to `grid_item one-half`.

If it is a Shopify Free Theme you can reach out to their support team and they usually are able to help you with it.